# Firebase fetch data in one computer but did not fetch data in another computer

Tags: windows, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I developed a desktop application with the help of JavaFX. after converting it into a jar file this jar file opens perfectly but data is not fetching from firebase's real-time database. Still, the same jar file is working correctly on different computers.
please help me...

I searched many websites but nothing was found, I know that there is no problem with the code the problem is in the computer or system because many computers are working correctly but some computers are not fetching data.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my problem, the only problem is the wrong date and time in the system that's why Firebase services are not working on that computer.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).